# Proving a sequence of partial sums is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think there's a mistake in my lecture notes but I'm always a little unsure when it comes to dealing with absolute values like this so I just want to check.

We have to show that for any complex number $z≠1$ with $|z|=1$, if $a_n=z^n$, the sequence of partial sums, $A_n$, is bounded. Here is what my lecturer did:

[image]

To me, it seems if you take the modulus of $z\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$ then you get $|z||\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}|=|\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}|=\frac{|1-z^n|}{|1-z|}$.

So doesn't that mean the first ≤ on the second line should be an = instead?

If not, could you explain what I'm missing? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first |z| can be replaced with equals sign.

Regarding rest of the proof, if you express z in exponential form, it can be observed that $z^{n}$ is a complex number of magnitude 1. In such a case $|1-z^{n}| <= 2$.